# Is dihydrogen the only example of overlap between two s orbitals?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, valence-bond-theory

I heard that $\ce{H2}$ is the only example of s–s orbital overlap. Can anyone give an example which contradicts this statement?

Comment: Metallic Li will do.

Comment: Are you suggesting that 1A and 2A mettalic bonds are all masses of covalent compound?

Comment: What's 1A and 2A? Also, no, a metal is definitely not a covalent compound. But there still is certain orbital overlap in it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  I meant the groups in modern periodic table.

Comment: Oh, of course. Well, they all are as good as Li in this regard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need particularly exotic things to get a counterexample. [Metal–metal bonding in mercury(I) compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_polycations) is quite prevalent, where the electronic configuration is $\ce{Hg+}$: $\ce{[Xe](4f^14)(5d^10)(6s^1)}$, and the bonding involves 6s–6s overlap. The prototypical example is the $\ce{Hg2^2+}$ cation, which features in mercury(I) chloride $\ce{(Hg2^2+)(Cl^-)2}$; this cation is valence isoelectronic to $\ce{H2}$.

Fundamentally, it is a relativistic contraction of the 6s orbital which makes such bonding common in Hg(I): see also [Why does mercury form polycations?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37141/16683). The bonding in alkali metal dimers is qualitatively similar, but significantly weaker.

If we play the "every bond has orbital overlap" card (i.e. not just covalent bonds, which I think is perfectly fair), then the delocalised bonding in Group 1 and 2 metals arises from overlap of *n*s orbitals on each atom to form [bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure), as has already been alluded to in the comments. Even simpler would be [lithium hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydride), which likely has *some* degree of 1s–2s orbital overlap, even though the bonding may be primarily ionic.

Answer (score 4):

Hydrogen forms, in addition to $\ce{H2}$, [ion clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_ion_cluster) of varying size.  Following are two prominent examples.

The [trihydrogen cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihydrogen_cation), $\ce{H3^+}$, is found in the interstellar medium and in the atmospheres of Jovian planets.  The three-center, two-electron bond that binds this ion together simultaneously covers all three atoms and all three atom-atom linkages, giving a strongly stabilized structure.

The hexahydrogen ion, $\ce{H6^+}$, mentioned in the first reference above, has a turnstile structure in which three dihydrogen units are linked together with three mutually orthogonal orientations; alternatively it may be viewed as two tri-hydrogen triangles joined vertex to vertex.  This species can be formed in solid hydrogen, where it migrates through an exchange mechanism similar to the [Grotthus mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism) of proton conduction in water and other protic solvents.