# Can metals have a net negative charge

Tags: ions, metal, transition-metals, formal-charge

Normal metals like sodium or Calcium have a positive charge as $\ce{Na}^+$ or $\ce{Ca}^{2+}$.
Transition metals have a loot of variable oxidation states.

Yesterday I read about Iridium in Wikipedia and it stated that

> a **+9** oxidation state has been found in $\ce{IrO_4^+}$

which is astounding for me...

So i was thinking can metals have a net negative charged ion also?

According to [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2XlW.jpg) :

> Ions: An atom or group of atoms gain an electric charge by gaining or losing an electron, usually through bonding. Cation: An atom loses electrons and is positive ex: $\ce{Ca^2^+}$. Anion: An atom gains electrons and is negative ex: $\ce{Cl-}$. Metals usually form cations while nonmetals usially  form anions. [source: chemwiki UCDavis]

Since it is written that metals *USUALLY* have positive charges which means there may be conditions or compounds when they have negative charges too. Is it possible?

Also can noble gases form ions too?

Comment: Addressing your noble gas ion question, they have been known for over 50 years to make compounds with formal positive charges on the noble gas atoms, though discrete noble gas cations (i.e. $\ce{Ng^{x+}}$) are not known in compounds.

Comment: More interestingly, regarding the possibility of noble gas *anions*, all noble gases up to radon have an endothermic electron affinity, and could not even in principle stabilize a negative charge on them. However, due to relativistic effects, the superheavy noble gas ununoctium [may be able to form an isolated $\ce{Uuo^-}$ anion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununoctium#Calculated_atomic_and_physical_properties), though it would presumably be quite reactive. Whether a compound can be made with a $\ce{Uuo^-}$ anion is not known.

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/bonds-between-metals-and-non-metals/6939#6939, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/except-pure-alloys-are-there-any-compounds-with-more-metal-elements-proportion/26548#26548

Comment: @Nocolau there is no longer "ununoctium".  It's now oganesson, Og.

Comment: Search “Alkalide” for information on things like $\ce{Na-}$ and other first column negative states

Comment: @nicolau "discrete noble gas cations are not known in compounds." We are closer than one might think with radon-fluorine compounds, where a complex ion $\ce{RnF^+}$ is evident. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These species usually do not exist in nature, but they can be synthesized.

1. Silver has been reduced in liquid ammonia to give $\ce{Ag-}$.
2. A lot of anionic metal carbonyl complexes $\ce{M(CO)_{n}^{m-}}$ have been synthesized:

#### -1

- $\ce{[V(CO)6]-}$, $\ce{[Nb(CO)6]-}$, $\ce{[Ta(CO)6]-}$, $\ce{[Mn(CO)5]-}$, $\ce{[Ir(CO)4]-}$, $\ce{[Co(CO)4]-}$, $\ce{[Rh(CO)4]-}$

#### -2

- $\ce{[Ti(CO)6]^{2-}}$, $\ce{[Zr(CO)6]^{2-}}$, $\ce{[Hf(CO)6]^{2-}}$, $\ce{[Fe(CO)4]^{2-}}$, $\ce{[Ru(CO)4]^{2-}}$, $\ce{[Os(CO)4]^{2-}}$

#### -3

- $\ce{[V(CO)5]^{3-}}$, $\ce{[Nb(CO)5]^{3-}}$, $\ce{[Ta(CO)5]^{3-}}$, $\ce{[Mn(CO)4]^{3-}}$, $\ce{[Re(CO)4]^{3-}}$

#### -4

- $\ce{[Cr(CO)4]^{4-}}$, $\ce{[Mo(CO)4]^{4-}}$

There's a review by *John E. Ellis*: [*Highly Reduced Metal Carbonyl Anions: Synthesis, Characteri's zation, and Chemical Properties*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0065-3055(08)60508-0) on these compounds.

---

**Edit**

While Christian Aichinger's comment concerning $\pi$-backbonding in metal carbonyls is correct, it is important to realize that $\ce{CO}$ is a neutral ligand!

With other words: The *Mond* process: $\ce{Ni(s) + 4CO -> Ni(CO)4}$, using nickel powder and carbon monoxide, is not a redox reaction and the oxidation state of the metal still is $0$ in the metal carbonyl.

Comment: The metal carbonyls have pretty much the same old positive oxidation state if we remove those carbonyls... But the Ag- is good ....

Comment: @NeilRoy Unless I got you completely wrong: Did you take into account that carbon monoxide is a **neutral** ligand?

Comment: Another noteworthy example would be CsAu which contains gold in the -1 oxidation state.

Comment: I don't fully agree with @NeilRoy, but even though CO is neutral, it can pull electron density away from the metal via [π backbonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_backbonding) ($ \ce{ M^{-}-C=O <-> M=C-O^{-} } $). I think it's helpful to remember that oxidation states are a helpful formalism to keep track of electrons, but they don't always describe the real electron distribution very well.

Comment: Very interesting examples of metal anions are the [alkalides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide) $\ce{Na^-}$, $\ce{K^-}$, $\ce{Rb^-}$, and $\ce{Cs^-}$. Yes that's right, **monoanions** of the familiar alkali metals! Who said old dogs can't learn new tricks?

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Change your comment into an answer

Comment: Or the answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89153/is-it-possible-to-have-anions-of-metals).

Comment: Question about alkalides: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53906/alkalide-compounds